# Making a GET call before leaving page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, get

**performing a GET in order to send data to an API before a user leaves the page can be seen as a performance issue.**

Is there an alternative or a way a developer can optimize the client side javascript?

---

One of the great examples is:
**Google Analytics!**

Comment: If you already have code to optimize it would be easier ;)

Comment: By default, Google Analytics doesn't send data either periodically or when exiting the page. It only sends data when a new page is loaded. This means that the time-on-site and bounce-rate only take into account the pages viewed prior to the last page.

You can use a beforeunload event or periodically send data to Analytics to capture activity on the last page loaded.
http://www.google.com/search?q=google+analytics+bounce+rate+last+page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't noticed too much of a hit in our applications when we bind to the **beforeunload** event:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    // Perform your GET 
});
```

Not sure if Google Analytics is doing it this way though.

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to perform an action before a user leaves the page.  If you have to make sure you capture data w/o the user submitting it manually, you could perform AJAX operations either when the user changes any input fields, or use setTimeout to periodically collect information and send it to the server.